# jQuery $.get or $.post for pagination?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a page where I have a list of company products, and I have created buttons for sorting and searching of products.

My action method looks like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CustomerProducts(ActivityViewModel activityModel) {
    // fetch products using web api and return partial view
}
```

I have written an **ActivityViewModel**

```
public class ActivityViewModel {
    public string customerId { get; set; }
    public int skip { get; set; }
    public int noOfRecords { get; set; }
    public DateTime? startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? endDate { get; set; }
    public string sortOrder { get; set; }
    public string searchText { get; set; }
    public string searchField { get; set; }
    public int? searchProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Now my question is when the user searches for specific products or sorts them, should the call to server be **jQuery $.get or $.post**?

I know differences between traditional **get** and **post** requests. If I stick to that rule, nothing is changing on the server side and this request can of course be cached. In that case, request should be get. But it's ajax scenarios where I am confused. How does the model binding work in this scenario? If I use ajax get for this purpose, will the **model binder** bind these values? What is the preferred way for such scenarios?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paging can be categorised as GETting data from the server therefore you should use `$.get` for it.Using `$.post` will also work but that doesn't mean you should use it.It's important to understand the differences between using the two - [GET vs POST in AJAX calls](https://www.sitepoint.com/key-differences-post/).

If you use common MVC paging concepts such as `PagedList` or `WebGrid` and inspect the traffic through Fiddler as you page through the list you will notice that it **ALWAYS** does an HTTP GET.

Also, just something to consider - why don't you use `WebGrid?`.It comes standard with ASP.NET MVC and exists in the `System.Web.Helpers.dll`, it supports paging and sorting out of the box, here's an example:

**Controller:**

```
public class Item
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class GridExampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Item> model = this.GetItems();
        return View(model);
    }

    private List<Item> GetItems()
    {
        var item1 = new Item { Description = "Item 1", Number = "1" };
        var item2 = new Item { Description = "Item 2", Number = "2" };
        var item3 = new Item { Description = "Item 3", Number = "3" };

        var item4 = new Item { Description = "Item 4", Number = "4" };
        var item5 = new Item { Description = "Item 5", Number = "5" };
        var item6 = new Item { Description = "Item 6", Number = "6" };

        return new List<Item> { item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6 };
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC_jqgrid_example.Helpers.Item>

@{
    Layout = null;
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, canSort: true, rowsPerPage: 3);
}


@if (Model.Any())
{
    @grid.GetHtml(
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Description", "Description", format: @<text> @item.Description</text>),
            grid.Column("Number", "Number", format: @<text> @item.Number</text>)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Model binder will bind, but your URL can be too long, so I think you should use post.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I tried using GET, but once the parameters were no longer null, some URL data started missing. Isn't there some better way? Without violating the W3C recommendation (of using GET instead of POST for fetching)? What if I want to cache the records?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `$.post()` because, for example, if the user types a product in the search bar or in fields and click on the button (or you have used `keyup()` upon text changed), an Ajax **POST** call will be made to the post version of action `CustomerProducts()` which should be only used for searching the required product.

The action will only hit upon Ajax call if Model binds successfully. To make sure that model binding is correct, you have to compare the data that is passed to the server in the `data` section of the Ajax call with your `ActivityViewModel` that your POST action is accepting. If the `ActivityViewModel` is not matching with your form data, you might have to create a separate ViewModel based upon your search form.

You then decide what to do based upon the `success` or `failure` response of the Ajax call that you have received. Debugging this can be helpful.

Comment: Yeah I am currently doing it the way you mentioned. It's working perfectly fine. The only thing that bugs me is that POST is not the recommended way to fetch data by W3C (or at least my perception is that). I was just wondering if there's some better way to solve this problem (some way where we don't have to use POST request).

Comment: According to your situation, other possible ways can be

1. Retrieve all the data from the database at once, serialize it in JSON and make an Ajax call to retrieve the required data from this JSON file.
2. Use ASP.NET SignalR for permanent connection. (It might be difficult to setup).

In both cases, you have to use POST because you have to make a call to the server for retrieving search result. Also inform us if you find a better way.

Comment: It's a bit late, but I tested different paging extensions e.g. `PagedList` and `WebGrid` using Fiddler. These extensions don't use POST for fetching. GET is always used for fetching data. I also read [RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) where it explains GET and POST in depth.